# How to update Recent File List in the CMFCRibbonBar

Tags: c++, mfc, recent-file-list

We have replaced VC++ VS2010 menu application with the CMFCRibbonBar. In the older menu driven version we had created our own user defined class derived from CRecentFileList. We overrode the UodateMenu method to add and delete files from the Recent File List. Now that we are using the CMFCRibbonBar, we are having problems getting the Recent Files list updated in the ribbon. the MRU list is properly updated everytime we open another file, but the Recent File list in the ribbon stays the same. If we close the application, then re-open it the Recent File list is updated properly. Any help will be extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you've used your own derived class from `CRecentFileList`, there is one possibility that changes to MFC have affected the way it's called - in particular if you have changed the `WINVER` definition in your project.

The ribbon bar doesn't do any more than route the commands for File/Open and File/Save through the MFC framework, and in each case they end up at some point in `CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList()`, which is what does the deed.

Now, in earlier versions of MFC (e.g. VS2008), that function was defined as follows:

```
void CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ENSURE_ARG(lpszPathName != NULL);
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(lpszPathName));

    if (m_pRecentFileList != NULL)
        m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName);
}
```

However, from (I think) VS2010 onward - certainly in VS2012 - that function now looks like this:

```
void CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ENSURE_ARG(lpszPathName != NULL);
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(lpszPathName));

    if (m_pRecentFileList != NULL)
    {
#if (WINVER >= 0x0601)
        m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName, m_pszAppID);
#else
        m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName);
#endif
    }
}
```

You can see that there is a new overload of `CRecentFileList::Add()` which may be affecting the logic in your derived class. If you step into that new code with the debugger, you can see that it's using Windows 7 shell API calls to add recent documents to the jump list (among other things), which you may want to do anyway.

In any case, as you've found that reloading the application correctly shows the updated list, I would think it would only be necessary to reload the list yourself after it's changed. To do this, you can override `CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList()` as follows:

```
void CYourApp::AddToRecentFileList(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList(lpszPathName);
    m_pRecentFileList->ReadList();
}
```

See if that helps.